# MaterialUI Grid direction=row not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a grid of buttons aligned in specific order, but I am having difficulties with making both buttons on the same row:

Expected:

[image]

Instead, row2 (the two columns in red), appear in a column direction (the second column goes bellow the first columnt, screenshot: http://prntscr.com/x4amxf) and not in a row direction like I am expecting them to be.

Here is my grid:

```
<Grid container direction="column"> // this is another container that wraps everything, not in the picture above
  <Grid item container direction="row"></Grid> // another row of stuff, not related, works just fine

  // picture represents this grid
  <Grid item container direction="row" spacing={1}>
    <Grid align="center" direction="row" justify="center" item container xs={1}>
      <Grid item container direction="column">
        <Grid item></Grid>
        <Grid item></Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container direction="column">
        <Grid item></Grid>
        <Grid item></Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Grid> 
</Grid>
```

I have tried to increase xs to 2 to see if its a size issue, but it just stretched the items.

And the actual code (but the structure above represents the same):

```
<Grid container direction="column">
  <Grid item container>
  </Grid>
  <Grid item container direction="row" spacing={1}>
    <Grid item>
      <AddPrice open={open} handleClosePopup={handleClose} item={item} />

      <IconButton variant="contained" onClick={handleClose}>
        <AddCircleOutlineIcon color="primary" style={{ fontSize: 40, marginRight: 5 }} />
        <Typography>Цена</Typography>
      </IconButton>
    </Grid>
    {item.prices.map(({ price, quantity }) => (
      <React.Fragment key={`itemPrice1${price}`}>
        <Grid align="center" direction="row" justify="center" item container xs={1}>
          <Grid item container direction="column">
            <Grid item>
              <Button>
                <Grid item direction="column" container>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Typography variant="button">{price} лв.</Typography>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item>
                    <Typography variant="button">
                      {quantity.available} {item.quantity.type}.
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          {editing && (
            <Grid item container direction="column">
              <Grid item>
                <IconButton style={{ border: "1px solid #f44336" }} variant="contained" color="secondary">
                  <DeleteForever color="secondary" style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
                </IconButton>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <IconButton style={{ border: "1px solid #3f51b5" }}>
                  <EditIcon color="primary" style={{ fontSize: 30 }} />
                </IconButton>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          )}
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </Grid>
  <Grid item container></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Basically, the editing buttons, should appear on the right of the price buttons.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6v50s?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the task correctly, you have to refactor your layout like this:

```
    <Grid container direction="column">
      <Grid item container direciton="row">
        Row1
      </Grid>
      <Grid align="center" direction="row" container>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
          <Grid item>BR</Grid>
          <Grid item>TXT</Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={2} style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
          <Grid item>EDIT</Grid>
          <Grid item>DELETE</Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Please, check out [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-rjf8l?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Thats it yes! There is something that I can't quite figure out about this Grid thingy, I am thinking about it like with bootstrap rows and columns, but apparently, not quite, can you provide a brief description of what the actual problem is with my code?

Comment: I think you're missing proper `container` and `item` props understanding. You have to avoid setting both of them true on a same `Grid` node in most cases.

Comment: you may be right, but after a bit of tinkering and comparing your code with mine, its not the additional container property that I had, its the size, i didnt have the xs={2} like you did, and it was simply stretching everyitem to xs=12 pushing the other column to the next row. Thanks!